# How can I make this code search only for posts and not pages? (wp_query)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

This is the code:

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$search_term=$_REQUEST['search-terms'];
if(empty($search_term))
$search_term=$_REQUEST['s'];
$wp_query->query("s=".$search_term);?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while(have_posts()):the_post(); global $post;?>
```

For some reason it shows both posts and pages in the results page. How can i exclude pages and show only posts?

I tried this but it's not working:

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
query_posts( $args );
$search_term=$_REQUEST['search-terms'];
if(empty($search_term))
$search_term=$_REQUEST['s'];
$wp_query->query("s=".$search_term);?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while(have_posts()):the_post(); global $post;?>
```

Please help is kinda urgent. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a post type to your query.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$search_term=$_REQUEST['search-terms'];
if(empty($search_term))
$search_term=$_REQUEST['s'];
$wp_query->query("post_type=post&s=".$search_term); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while(have_posts()):the_post(); global $post;?>
```

I changed your first code

Comment: Yea, i figured out where to place your code and it's working now. Thank you very much. I've been trying to make it work for hours.

Comment: Well, if it worked, then accept the answer by clicking on the big V near my answer :P